# Flutter. The chat app has a problem sending messages

Tags: flutter

There is such a problem in my Flutter application - when sending messages from the _handleSubmitted method, the first thing I do is display a list of messages _messages = []; then I send the message to the database. Everything works fine, but in the fetchMessagesPeriodically method - when I receive messages, I update the list of _messages = []; and at this moment, the message (one) that I sent disappears, and after one second appears in the same place. How can this problem be solved? I receive messages through a timer, you can say, and this affects the flicker of messages - I understand this, but there must be some way out!?

```
class _ChatUsersState extends State<ChatUsers> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  List<ChatMessage> _messages = [];
  List<dynamic> messages = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Color(0xff2a2a2a),
              Color(0xff0a090e),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: _messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final ChatMessage message = _messages[index];
                  final bool isMe = message.id == currentUserID;
                  return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                    isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: isMe ? Colors.white : Color(0xff262628),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        margin: isMe
                            ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 80)
                            : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, right: 80),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: isMe
                              ? CrossAxisAlignment.start
                              : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: isMe
                                  ? Text(
                                message.message,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.brown[900],
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              )
                                  : Text(message.message,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(),
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xff0a090e),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: const LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.deepPurple,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.deepPurple,
                Colors.green,
              ],
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.8),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xff0a090e),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, right: 1),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/img_6.png',
                                width: 25,
                                height: 25,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 15,
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextField(
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  controller: _textController,
                                  decoration:
                                  const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                    hintText: 'Сообщение',
                                    hintStyle:
                                    TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/img_5.png',
                                  width: 25,
                                  height: 25,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  String message = _textController.text;
                                  if (message.isNotEmpty) {
                                    _handleSubmitted(
                                        _textController.text);
                                    _textController.clear();
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    try {

      // Создаем новое сообщение до отправки запроса
      ChatMessage newMessage = ChatMessage(
        user_id: 0,
        id: currentUserID,
        message: text,
        timestamp: '',
        senderUserId: 0,
      );

      setState(() {
        _textController.clear();
        _messages.insert(0, newMessage); // Добавляем новое сообщение в начало списка
      });

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      int? userIds = prefs.getInt('user_id');
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(API.SendMessageChat));

      if (widget.user_idWidget != null && widget.senderUserIdWidget != null) {
        request.fields['user_id'] = widget.user_idWidget.toString();
        request.fields['senderUserId'] = widget.senderUserIdWidget.toString();
      } else {
        // Обработка случая отсутствия значений user_id и senderUserId
        // Можно вернуть false или выбросить исключение
      }

      request.fields['id'] = userIds.toString();
      request.fields['message'] = text;
      request.fields['timestamp'] = DateTime.now().toString();

      var response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        // Обработка ошибки отправки сообщения
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      // Обработка ошибки
    }


  }


  void fetchMessagesPeriodically() {
    const Duration delay = Duration(seconds: 1); // Задаем интервал в секундах
    Timer.periodic(delay, (Timer timer) async {
      try {
        var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(API.GetAllMessageChat),
          body: {
            'senderUserId': widget.senderUserIdWidget.toString(),
            'user_id': widget.user_idWidget.toString(),
          },
        );
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
          List<ChatMessage> chats =
          data.map((item) => ChatMessage.fromJson(item)).toList();
          setState(() {
            _messages.clear();
            _messages.addAll(chats.reversed);
          });
        } else {
          print('Failed to load messages');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchMessagesPeriodically();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a video for batter understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you do not have a clear Single-source-of-truth, i.e. having a single, authoritative source for storing and managing messages data. Your local list of chat message (*`_messages`*), upon successful receipt and from the server and the data pushed back from it, be updated with the relevant data. When getting the response from the server you should probably handle conflict resolutions, using **UID's**, timestamps and event maybe a chat "status" (sent, delivered, read, ...), and then update the UI to show those changes to the user.

Apart from that, your problem may be linked to how the widget tree is identifying the chat messages widgets. It could be solved by defining a Widget class which represents a chat message, name `ChatMessageTile` for example, and **providing a `ValueKey` to that widget with the UID of the message as value**.